# DB2 HADR+TSA Why my IBM.Application always stay in online

Tags: db2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHPqZ.png)
I have already completed the HADR on node1 and node2
preprpnode,mkdomain,IBM.TieBreaker and so on (all succeeded)
finally I executed commandline below:

```
mkrsrc IBM.Application Name="apHADR" NodeNameList="{'dbnode1','dbnode2'}" StartCommand="/usr/sbin/rsct/sapolicies/db2/hadrV115_start.ksh" StopCommand="/usr/sbin/rsct/sapolicies/db2/hadrV115_stop.ksh" MonitorCommand="/usr/sbin/rsct/sapolicies/db2/hadrV115_monitor.ksh" 
MonitorCommandPeriod=30 
MonitorCommandTimeout=30 
StartCommandTimeout=300 
StopCommandTimeout=300 
UserName="root"
```

and then :
`lsrsrc -Ab IBM.Application`
get rusult :
`OpState:1 //online`
it just can't change the state whatever I try
`chrg -o online rg`
or
`chrg -o offline rg`
or
`stoprsrc`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8Np8.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxN27.png)

Comment: Don't ever try to configure the Db2 HADR resources manually unless you completely know the TSAMP resource model for Db2 HADR databases and all things around the integration Db2 and TSAMP. Remove the whole TSAMP cluster and use the [db2haicu](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=files-db2ha-sample-hadrxml) tool to create a TSAMP cluster for Db2 HADR.